# IF condition inside an array

Tags: php, yii

In trying to use an `if` condition inside an `array`, but its not working. How can I fix that?

Code:

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return array(
        'withRelated'=>array(
            'class'=>'ext.wr.WithRelatedBehavior',
        ),
        Yii::app()->controller->id != 'apiv1' ?
        'datetimeI18NBehavior'=>array(
            'class' => 'ext.DateTimeI18NBehavior',
        ), : false,
    );
}
```

Error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW) in .../models/Users.php on line 77
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with:

```
'datetimeI18NBehavior' => ( Yii::app()->controller->id != 'apiv1' ) ? array(
    'class' => 'ext.DateTimeI18NBehavior',
) : false,
```

Other (much clear) solution:

```
public function behaviors()
{
    $behaviors = array(
        'withRelated'=>array(
            'class'=>'ext.wr.WithRelatedBehavior',
        )
    );

    if ( Yii::app()->controller->id != 'apiv1' ) {
         $behaviors['datetimeI18NBehavior'] = array(
            'class' => 'ext.DateTimeI18NBehavior'
        );
    }

    return $behaviors;
}
```

Comment: I got Yii Framework error `Object configuration must be an array containing a "class" element.`, because I cannot declare the `behavior` array empty.

Comment: That second solution works, but I cannot use an `if` condition inside the array?

Comment: As you said, you cannot handle `null` value - so it's impossible, because if you use condition inside an array, key has to have some value.

Answer (score 5):

This is the proper approach to your problem.

```
public function behaviors()
{
    $arr = array(
        'withRelated'=>array(
            'class'=>'ext.wr.WithRelatedBehavior',
        )        
    );
    $bool = Yii::app()->controller->id != 'apiv1' ? true : false;
    if($bool) {
        $arr['datetimeI18NBehavior'] = array(
            'class' => 'ext.DateTimeI18NBehavior',
        );
    } else {
        $arr[] = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function behaviors() {
return array(
'withRelated'=>array(
'class'=>'ext.wr.WithRelatedBehavior',
),
Yii::app()->controller->id != 'apiv1' ?
'datetimeI18NBehavior'=>array(
'class' => 'ext.DateTimeI18NBehavior',
) : false,
);
}
```

remove the comma after the parentheses

Comment: Got the same error `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW) in .../models/Users.php on line 77`